# Smoothly Looping Periodic Trigonometric Functions

Tags: game-physics, trigonometry, particle-system

Unfortunately, I'm a novice programmer but a relatively experienced mathematician.

I wanted to get into developing games, and I think I've almost mastered the basic linear algebra mathematics behind some things like OpenGL. Unfortunately, I don't have the technical know-how yet to do graphical simulations.

As a bit of an elementary exercise, I wanted to try and simulate the continuous movement of a particle in a circular path. I used the simple parametrization

```
double t=0;
double x = cos(t), y = sin(t);
```

I'm aware that double has a range of *1.7E +/- 308* according to Microsoft. My question would then be, "How can I ensure the smoothest continuous circular loop of the particle?" The problem that I thought might happen is that if the program ran long enough as *t* grew larger and larger, we'd reach the point where *t* would reset to its lowest value and that might cause a "jump" in the position of the particle.

I've thought about this and I wondered if it would be necessary to create a mapping for *t* from [1.7E-308, 1.7E+308) → [0,2π). Would this help prevent any position "jumps"? Or is there a problem in doing this that I'm not forseeing? My plan would've been to increase *t* at a predetermined rate, which I haven't determined yet. But I see the rate at which *t* increases determines how fast the *x* and *y* coordinates change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You worry too much. Or at least about the wrong thing. The sun will turn into a red giant, and swallow earth, long before you exceed the maximum of a double by adding small increments.

A slightly more serious problem is that the absolute precision of `t` decreases as its magnitude increases. This is based on the fact that the precision of a double is relative to its magnitude. Even that will take a very long time before it becomes a real problem, but it happens long before `t` exceeds the double range.

Another related and more real concern is that the `cos()`/`sin()` implementation might become less precise for larger input values. The high quality implementations that you would typically find in a standard library, or in hardware, would hopefully reduce the argument, so that should not be much of a problem.

All of that being said, avoiding any of these problems, as remote as they may be in reality, is so easy that you might as well take care of it. You simply reduce the value of `t` as soon as it exceeds 2 * pi after incrementing it:

```
t += tInc;
if (t > 2.0 * M_PI)
{
    t -= 2.0 * M_PI;
}
```

With this, the value will always stay between 0 and 2 * pi.

BTW: It should be *very* rare that you need double precision for anything related to graphics. Using variables and constants of type `float` should be sufficient unless you have a very unusual use case. The graphics library you will be using will typically operate in `float` precision anyway, so using `double` in your own code will just use additional memory, and result in a lot of type conversions.

Comment: I would think that using M_PI for a manual argument reduction would lead to an ever increasing phase-shift in the computed sine and cosine values compared to `sincos(i * angle_increment, &s, &c)`, since M_PI merely approximates mathematical π, but depending on the use case, that may not matter here. Not-broken implementations of `sin(), cos(), sincos()` will use a sufficiently accurate internal approximation to  π to avoid the phase shift issue.

Comment: @njuffa What are you comparing to? No matter how you handle this, you'll have errors due to limited floating point precision. As I explained, the `t` value itself will lose precision if it grows larger. At some point, when it's precision becomes larger than the increment, it would stop increasing entirely. That would seem like a much more severe problem.

Comment: I fully agree that the granularity of the floating-point representation increases with growing magnitude of the argument causing a problem eventually. Since the asker uses `double` it will take many angle increments before that turns into a significant problem, in particular if multiplication is used to tally the angle increments. My point is that manual argument reduction by `M_PI` in the manner suggested above is not usually preferable to the use of properly implemented trigonometric functions from the C/C+ standard math library, as these include a more accurate internal argument reduction.